# Installing bootstrap and font-awesome in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried installing bootstrap and font-awesome in angular app but it's not working.

I used `npm install --save bootstrap font-awesome` and I added the bootstrap and font-awesome in the angular.json like this

`"styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "node_modules/font-awesome/css/all.min.css", "src/styles.css"], "scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"`

Yet when I run
`<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`

in the app.component.html page it's not working.

I am using angular 15.1.4, what am I not doing right please.

Comment: Do you get errors in the console? In the network tab, do you see the **woff** and **woff2** files downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Add your font-awesome code in div container or an a class container, that should be fine in my opinion, you should also check bootstrap examples given at https://fontawesome.com/v4/examples/#bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ./ before node_modules folder. Also check if you have added it under build or test configuration in angular.json file. It should be under build configuration.